# how to send handleTheme() function to routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

This is my App.js file I want to send handleTheme() to routes.js through routing but i don't know how to do it.

```
import routes from './routes';
import { themeSaver } from '../serviceWorker';

const App = () => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = themeSaver('isdarkMode', false);
  const routing = useRoutes(routes);

  const handleTheme = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      {routing}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and this my routes.js file i have written handletheme() to show where i want to pass that function

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    element: <DashboardLayout handleTheme={handleTheme} />,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', element: <Dashboard /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
      { path: '404', element: <NotFound /> },
      { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/app/dashboard" /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
    ],
  }
];

export default routes;
```

I have tried lots of thing but i don't get Please help ....Thank you in adv

Comment: you can achieve this functionality using context if you want to provide this to all child components. Can you share your code on code sandbox ??

Comment: your code is not looking right